# How should I approach: Wordpress Social Login (web) and Flutter (mobile)

Tags: wordpress, flutter, authentication

I'm a little bit lost on how should I approach my objective, which is adding Social login to both Wordpress site and flutter and integrate for its content in using wordpress as backend.

- From flutter perspective, I could use specific plugins to oAuth to
  each provider or even use Firebase.
- From Wordpress site, lots of plugins to achieve same functionality.

My first thought was to use firebase to stablish some sort of workflow

```
1 User tries to Login in Flutter with any social provider
2 I check if user has already an account in Firebase
2a If it does, go and fetch the user token in Wordpress
2b if it does not, I create the user in Firebase and then do a callback to wordpress site to create it and obtain the wordpress token
```

But still, not sure if that would work. What would happen if same user then tries to log in on the Wordpress Site using same / any provider, will it create a new user on wordpress site? Will it tell him that, he is already registered or would just login with no issue.

I apologise for the novice question.

Also, would like to avoid as much as posible paid plugins solutions, as this is a learning curve for me, not a monetary issue or professional work.

Thanks in advance

---

Update:

Thanks for answering, I did review such plugin, but as I mentioned I was aiming to learn on how to accomplish such integration. What I ended up doing was actually was quite a simple but very clunk solution which covers my needs.

- First I ended up creating a Firebase Account, added FireStore, and all required social media login (you have plenty of videos on how to accomplish that)
- In flutter installed the FireBase Core plugin to do the integration between both.
- After that I created a few rest api end points in wordpress, which handles the response from Firebase.

So in other words for the use case I was interested (User Auth), Firebase Handles Google, Facebook, and the N social media login... after they are logged in flutter (I have the token for the social media), I then query rest Api from wordpress in order to know if the user already exists (update) o I need to create it. If it's created then I create a cookie (Why a Cookie? will handle WooCommerce Cart Items and have them in sync by default), but you can generate a Token if you need, and that's it. User is created a Firebase with corresponding Token and In wordpress generating a Cookie for user activities.  Bellow you can find a rest Api end point going from one of the Social Media as an example.. from flutter you have several on YouTube.

```
public function loginFacebook($args = null)
  {
    $parsedArgs = $args->get_params();
    $userToken = $parsedArgs["token"];

    if (empty($userToken)) {
      return YaguaretePluginApiCommonFunctions::wpError(
        "error_response_token_empty",
        401
      );
    }

    //facebook arguments
    $fields = "id,name,first_name,last_name,email,picture.type(large)";
    $enable_ssl = true;

    $response = YaguaretePluginApiCommonFunctions::wpUrlRequest(
      "https://graph.facebook.com/me/?fields=" .
        $fields .
        "&access_token=" .
        $userToken
    );

    if (!isset($response["email"])) {
      return YaguaretePluginApiCommonFunctions::wpError(
        "error_response_token_invalid",
        401
      );
    }

    if (!email_exists($response["email"])) {
      $userName = $response["name"];
      while (username_exists($userName)) {
        $i++;
        $user_name = strtolower($userName) . "." . $i;
      }

      $userData = [
        "user_login" => $userName,
        "user_email" => $response["email"],
        "user_pass" => wp_generate_password(
          $length = 12,
          $include_standard_special_chars = false
        ),
        "display_name" => $result["name"],
        "first_name" => $result["first_name"],
        "last_name" => $result["last_name"],
      ];

      //inserting user
      $user = wp_insert_user($userData);
    }

    $user = get_user_by("email", $response["email"]);
    add_user_meta(
      $user->ID,
      "YaguaretePluginSocialAvatar",
      $response["picture"]["data"]["url"],
      true
    );

    return YaguaretePluginApiCommonFunctions::wpInternalCallGetUser(
      $response["email"]
    );
  }
```

Any way, thanks for replying!

Comment: Hi, does any one have any hint on the subject?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that you have found the solution. If not, you can take a look at using FirebaseUI Web on WordPress via the `Integrate Firebase PRO` plugin.

https://firebase-wordpress-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auth/work-with-firebaseui-web.html

The authentication on WordPress will be handled by Firebase Authentication, so they will have the same userbase.